# how to count each values of a coloumn but different conditionals

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

i have table

```
nim              jumlah        jurusan        angkatan     word
310910022          2     teknik informatika    2009        create
310910022          2     teknik informatika    2009        login
320910022          3              SI           2009        asem
320910022         6              SI           2009        bold
```

I want to summarize this table, to this:

```
nim              jumlah           
310910022          4         
320910022          9
```

How can I do that in PL/SQL?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
select nim, sum(jumlah)  
group by    nim 
order by    nim
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT
    nim,
    sum(jumlah) AS jumlah
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE nim = 310910022 AND nim = 320910022
GROUP BY nim;
```

Comment: `nim` can't be equal to two values at once... presumably you meant to use `OR` or `IN` rather than `AND`, but I'm not sure the OP wanted a filter at all.